# jQuery .val() is not working on mac pac in chrome browser

Tags: jquery, html

Hello Friends This is html code.

```
<select name="map_style" class="map_style">
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
    <option value="4">4</option>
    <option value="5">5</option>
</select>
<div class="selected-answer">Select</div>
```

This is my html code and this is my jQuery Code.

```
$('body').on('click', '.map_style', function() {
      alert(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

This code is working fine on every browser.

but this code is not working on MAC PC in Chrome Browser.

My Chrome Browser Version is 33.0.1750.117

This is working on iphone fine but not working on mac chrome.

Comment: not error but is not return value. not return any kind of warning or error.

Comment: @renishkhunt: alert some text instead of value to check either alert is working or not. If not then check browser popup blocked settings.

Comment: @renishkhunt: Open New Incognito Window in Chrome and type your URL in it. It might solve your problem.

Comment: @A.K Thank for replay i try but this not work.

Comment: Have you opened New Incognito Window in Chrome?

Comment: @A.K Yes Dear i try but not working.

Comment: Actually I have faced same issue in chrome for PC. And the issue was that I checked the checkbox of the alertbox to be prevent in future. Then I opened New Incognito Window and it was working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `change()` event instead of `click()`, so change your code to:

```
$(document).on('change', '.map_style', function() {
      alert(parseInt($(this).val()));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you're trying to achieve, but if it's the value of the dropdown you're after I'd use code similar to this instead:

```
$('.map_style').on('change', function() {
  alert($(this).val());
});
```

This would alert the value of the selected item in the dropdown upon changes in the dropdown